# No .htaccess file is working with Laravel Lumen 5.2

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, lumen

I've tried almost every possible option with .htaccess file in my lumen's public folder but non of them are giving me Pretty URLs.

In previous versions of Lumen I hadn't touched any of the .htaccess rules and yet everything used to work perfectly with the shipped default .htaccess file.
But in this new version 5.2 nothing seems to work.

the default is as follows :

```
# Apache configuration file
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

# Note: ".htaccess" files are an overhead for each request. This logic     should
# be placed in your Apache config whenever possible.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and
# features. "+FollowSymLinks" must be enabled for this to work symbolically.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any thoughts ?!

Answer (score 0):

In you apache config file (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) you must change the "AllowOverride" to "All":

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```